# Unable To Access Port Forwarded Content via Domain Name/Public IP Address From Within LAN

Tags: networking, iptables, router, lan

I have iptables setup to forward Traefik ports 80 and 443 to WAN, and am able to view the content via my public IP address and registered domain name from outside of my LAN (tested on mobile with WiFi disabled). If I attempt to access the external IP address or domain name from within my LAN it fails.

**Firewall Rules**

```
# Set default policies for table
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# wan0 = ISP
# lan0 = LAN

# Traefik
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wan0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.20:80
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wan0 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.20:443

# ISP
-A POSTROUTING -o wan0 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -i wan0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -i wan0 -j DROP

# ISP
-A FORWARD -i wan0 -o lan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lan0 -o wan0 -j ACCEPT

# Forward ports 80 and 443 to Traefik
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.1.20 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.1.20 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -o wan0 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

Why is it that I am unable to access my public IP address from within my LAN?

Comment: The overall why is described eg there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback .